# how to disply numbers with format(1234->as 1,234) while selecting values from database

Tags: php, mysql

How to display numbers with format(1234->as 1,234) while selecting values from database

```
SELECT rates,invoice FROM data;
```

Now **Rates** are displaying as **235693** like this,but i want display it as **2,35,693**.

Comment: Use this : SELECT FORMAT(235693,0);

Answer (score 2):

you can use function : number_format($number)

```
<?php
   $number = 10000;
   $formatted_number = number_format($number);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `format` function

```
SELECT FORMAT(235693,0);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that satisfies "while selecting values from database" premise of the question.

Comment: hi,but i am using variable rates..but you have shown number,,is it possible like this SELECT FORMAT($rates,0);..i am reading variable not number.

Comment: yes of course :) pass the query to db and it will get formatted value. What would change is You are passing value stored in Variable Instead of Number. It will work.

Comment: @RaghuDarshan when you want solution , please enter All necessary code as per your requirement/question. Here you want  dynamic $rate, but you haven't specified in your Question.

Answer (score 1):

use this in `php`

```
money_format(string,number);
```

Comment: you should fetch from Db itself in currency form. Why use php if it can be done by mysql itself and php just has to **show** the number on the page? No need to implement logic in php.

Comment: It depends purely on the situation/context, you can not cease putting logic in `PHP` or become totally dependent on `MySQL`- eg. sometimes its not possible to change DB query as it will affect other parts of an application aswell, best is to put logic using `PHP`.

Comment: Please **Read** the question properly. He says **while selecting values from database**. Means he wants to get right from SQL query. He **doesnt** want to convert **while displaying** (means in php).

Comment: If he wants this to be done in MySQL then why he has tagged this question  in PHP ???

Comment: hi,i need to select rates from database and i need to display in table with proper number format as i shown above..but it displaying with normal number as(56239) but it should display as 56,239.        $content .= '</td><td>';
$content .= $rates;

Answer (score 1):

You also use PHP function -

```
number_format($num)
```

Also look on link - http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php